# Determine if $f''(0)$ exists in a piecewise function

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I have the following problem:

Determine if $f''(0)$ exists if

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} e^{-\frac{1}{x}}\sin e^{\frac{1}{x}} & x > 0 \\ 0& x \leq 0 \end{cases}$$

Clearly, when approaching from the left of $0$, the second derivative would be equal to $0$. But I'm struggling with the right hand side. For $x>0$, I have only managed to determine $f'(x)=\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}\sin(e^{\frac{1}{x}})-e^{-\frac{1}{x}}e^{\frac{1}{x}}\cos(e^{\frac{1}{x}})}{x^2}=\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{x}}\sin(e^{\frac{1}{x}})-\cos(e^{\frac{1}{x}})}{x^2}$ using the product rule, but I'm not sure if I should find $f''(0)$ right away with rules, but rather use the form $f''(0)=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'(x)-f'(0)}{x-0}$, although I'm not sure how I would solve that limit either. Or maybe I'm wrong and there's a method I'm not seeing here.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: First things first: What is $f'(0)$? You also might want to simplify your expression for $f'(x)$ to see more clearly what's happening.

Comment: For this kind of functions, it is common to use definitions to determine $f_+'$ (or $f_-'$) at some point. In this question, $f'_+(0)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0+}\dfrac{e^{\frac{-1}{x}}\sin e^{\frac{1}{x}}}{x}$, then try the substitution $t=\dfrac{1}{x}$

Comment: Thanks! I tried calculating the limit but don't know how I would find a solution without using L'Hopital's rule, as you get $\lim_{t\to\infty+}\frac{tsin(e^t)}{e^t}$ and I can't find any method using the standard limits.

Comment: Hint: $|t\sin e^t|\leq |t|$ , and  if we denote $\max\{i\in\mathbb{Z}| i\leq t\}$ by $[t]$, then for sufficiently large $t$ we have$e^t>2^t\geq 2^{[t]}=(1+1)^{[t]}$ (by the binomial theorem) $\geq C_{[t]}^0+C_{[t]}^1+C_{[t]}^2=\frac{1}{2}[t]^2+\dfrac{[t]}{2}+1>\dfrac{1}{2}[t]^2\geq\dfrac{1}{2}(t-1)^2>\dfrac{1}{4}t^2$. Now combine the two inequality.

Comment: Note that $t e^{-t}\to 0$ for $t\to \infty$ and that $\sin e^t$ is bounded. You can use the Squeeze Theorem to compute $f'(0)$. Then I suggest you first check if $f'(x)$ is **continuous** in $0$ or not. If it is not, then for sure it is not differentiable, and thus $f''(0)$ will not be defined.